# Fit Object3D inside Variable Width Canvas Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have an object3D of width 100 in my scene centred at the origin. The camera has an FOV of 50 and I would like this to remain constant. I am currently positioning the camera with

```
var camDistance = (100/2)/Math.tan(50/2 * Math.PI/180);
var camHeight = camDistance * (6/25);
camera.position.set(0,camHeight,camDistance);
camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
```

This is looks good for larger displays but on mobile the object extends past the edges of the screen. I want to vary the distance from the camera to the object so that the object always occupies the same percentage of the screen horizontally, no matter what size viewport it is loaded on. What I thought should work is

```
var camDistance = (100/2)/Math.tan(50/2 * Math.PI/180) * (1700/window.innerWidth);
```

Since the object occupies about 1700px with this fov. This sort of works except the object is now too far away on very small screen widths and too close on very large screen widths.

Is there a way to actually make the object occupy the same horizontal percentage of the viewport instead of the poor approximation that I have come up with? Preferably a solution that avoids the magical-ness of 1700px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you are only interested in fitting the width, not the height, of the object and screen.

It would have helped if you had added a HTML snippet of the problem in question, so I could try solutions for your application, but this is what I could come up with:

```
let dz = objectWidth/(2 * Math.tan(camera.fov/2) * camera.aspect);
camera.position.set(0, camHeight, margin + dz);
```

Here, `margin` is some `z` value that you can specify. You also need to make sure that `camera.aspect` corresponds to the actual aspect ratio of the window (below is how I would dynamically update it for a fullscreen application):

```
function onResize() {
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    let height = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

This works in a sandbox I set up for myself, but please let me know if it can be applied to your application too or if there is something I haven't taken into account.

Comment: Hi Berthur, thanks thats pretty close to what I wanted to do. Unfortunately when the viewport is very small the object occupies too little of the canvas and vice versa when the viewport is too large. What I'm working on is at seanaye.github.io your suggestion is on line 13 of script.js. Sorry if code is a bit messy I'm new to three.js

Comment: Have you tried different `objectWidth`s? When I try it on your code, `50` it seems to work quite nicely. Not sure if I might have missed a coefficient or something. How does it work for you?

Comment: setting it to 50 approximates it close enough. Thank you.